# Can you get stalled in Firetop Mountain?

Tags: firetop-mountain

During a recent game I almost got in a repeated position FP vs FP with my opponent, with a resulting Paralysis+Protection situation on both sides, but one of us broke away from that position just a turn before it became fully settled.
Can the game get stalled in that position (or in another position)? what happens then? is it a draw or a potentially neverending match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A never-ending double paralyze can lead to a deadlock situation. Especially if the is an Elemental that both mages have to be protected from. So, Yes, it can turn into this :

```
FFF...
PPP...
```

for both mages.

Hopefully, 2 paralyze spells cast on the same target cancel each other, so by casting your own paralyze spell on yourself, you will cancel the other one.

And moreover (and this has been a rule modification to put less power into paralyze spell), there is the fact that : if another **enchantment** spell (i.e. Amnesia, Confusion, Charm Person, Charm Monster or Fear) is cast on the same person as a paralyze spell, the other spell is "stronger" in the sense that the paralyze spell is cancelled on that turn. This could be used to break the FFF. (Amnesia is not a good choice ;-)

Comment: I can see your points about breaking away from paralysis, but, if you need to keep the protection up (for example, as you mentioned, if you have an Elemental in play and not enough damage points to survive unprotected) you can't cast another enchantment, while doesn't metter if you cast the paralysis on yourself or on the opponent: both will keep playing FP vs. FP, regardless of the target. The real point is that you CAN actually find yourself in a neverending deadlock, where both players are foorced to play FP. I guess in that case the players should contact the Janitor or agree for a draw...

Comment: Actually I play to have fun. If someone seems to stay forever into this FFFPPP situation. I cast paralyze on myself and surrender the very next turn. I'm there for the fun, not to win.